# Python: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 2: '1001001 1101101 ...."

Tags: python, bitstring

My XOR accepts two bitstrings and returns the XOR value of those two strings. I don't think the getXor function is reading the bitstring as integers and I've tried making changes but I'm not certain where as none of my efforts have worked.

```
import random

def getCaesar(message, key):
    enc = ""
    for char in message: 
        if char == ' ':
            enc = enc + char
        elif  char.isupper():
            enc = enc + chr((ord(char)+key-65)%26+65)
        elif char.islower():
            enc = enc + chr((ord(char) + key - 97) % 26 + 97)
        else:
            enc = enc +chr((ord(char) + key - 33) % 32 + 33)

    return enc

def getBinary(bitstr):
    bit=' '.join(format(ord(char), 'b') for char in bitstr)
    return bit

def getBitstr(k):
    result=""
    for num in range(0,k):
        result=''.join(str(random.randint(0,1))for num in range(k))
    return result

def getXor(a,b):
    result = int(a,2) ^ int(b,2)
    return '{0:b}'.format(result)


f=open("NoWar.txt", mode="r")
l=f.read()

binary=getBinary(l)
a=str(binary)
size=len(binary)
key=getBitstr(size)
b=str(key)
x=getXor(a,b)


cipher=getCaesar(key,4)
cipher="".join(cipher)
cipherF=open("ciphertext.txt", mode="w")
cipherF.write(cipher)
cipherF.close()
```

The error calls out:

```
result = int(a,2) ^ int(b,2)
```

With the error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 2: '1001001 1101101 1110000 1100101 1100001 1100011 1101000 1101101 1100101 1101110 1110100'

How do I fix this?

Comment: The spaces in the middle of the string make it invalid as a binary number.

Comment: Make a [mcve] and I bet you'll find the problem/solution yourself

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Ok, I removed the spaces using a=a.replace(" ",""), thank you. I thought the int(a,2) would work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove whitespace, try a.replace(' ', '') and same for b.